# An grouped array of elemtens by offset().top?

Tags: jquery

I've a set of elements:

```
jQuery.each(_this._elements, function (i, element) {
               ...
            });
```

How can I produce an array with these elements grouped by element.offset().top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one hand-made solution is

```
var items = [
    { offset: function() { return { top: 3 }}}, 
    { offset: function() { return { top: 2 }}}, 
    { offset: function() { return { top: 3 }}}, 
    { offset: function() { return { top: 1 }}}
];

var temp = {};

$.each(items, function(i, elem) {
    var top = elem.offset().top;

    if (temp[top]) {
        temp[top].push(elem);
    } else {
        temp[top] = [elem];
    }
})

var result = []; //array of arrays
$.each(temp, function(k, elems) {
    result.push(elems)
})

console.log(result);
```

replace my `items` with your `_this._elements`